# How to implement Next Auth v.5 for external API login in Next js 14 and app router

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, django-rest-framework, next-auth

The documentation for Next Auth is mostly outdated examples and, as I understand it, it is still being finalized.

In reality, it is very difficult to find information on how to do this. The docs of Next Auth are real pain and mess for me. I spent so many hours watching video tutorials and reading related articles, but it seems everything is changing so fast, that all the info is already old.

I was actually trying to adapt the authentication system from the tutorial on the official web site
of Next js,but obviously something I did wrong. I get an error like:

In VSCode fronend console I get errors like:

```
Response from API: {
  user: { id: 4, username: 'bob', email: 'rodopi1000@gmail.com' },
  refresh: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTcxMDUyNjUzMiwiaWF0IjoxNzEwNDQwMTMyLCJqdGkiOiJkMzI3MjJkNjM1MTQ0NTE5YTQ3ODEzYmE0YTYzYjc0NiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjR9.bUEP8vq0yhbRICtXjowThZ98Z77Fh9ArhLHWnflCbaA',
  access: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNzEwNDQwNDMyLCJpYXQiOjE3MTA0NDAxMzIsImp0aSI6IjBjOTE5MzM5YWNhZTQ4MmVhNzZmMTRjZTFkNWY0YzhlIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6NH0.M0F-yIQ3hitTvbom-JVeWQqlfaEEesYADFPFlDU8Mxw'
}
[auth][error] CallbackRouteError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
[auth][cause]: TypeError: "ikm"" must be an instance of Uint8Array or a string

............

[auth][details]: {
  "provider": "credentials"
}
Authentication Error: CallbackRouteError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
    at Module.callback (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:437:23)

....................


type: 'CallbackRouteError',
  kind: 'error',
  [cause]: {
    err: TypeError: "ikm"" must be an instance of Uint8Array or a string
```

I would be grateful for any help.

I have a backend on Django, DRF, also used JWT Simple, but it is not important.

Backend creates endpoints:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login/
127.0.0.1:8000/auth/register/
127.0.0.1:8000/auth/refresh/token
```

They all work correctly. Checked using Postman.

In the frontend in Next js 14:
In the project root i have **auth.config.ts** with the following code:

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isHomepage = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/");
      if (isHomepage) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/", nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [], // Add providers with an empty array for now
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;
```

**auth.ts:**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";
import { API_URL } from "@/config";

export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" }, 
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth/login/`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: credentials.username,
            password: credentials.password,
          }),
        });

        const data = await res.json();
        console.log("Ответ от API:", data);

        if (res.ok) {
          return {
            id: data.user.id,
            username: data.user.username,
            email: data.user.email,
            accessToken: data.access, 
            refreshToken: data.refresh,
          } as any;
        }

        if (!res.ok) {
          console.error("API request error:", data);
          return null; 
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

**middleware.ts:**

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { AUTH_SECRET } from "@/config";

export async function middleware(req: any) {
  const session = await getToken({ req, secret: AUTH_SECRET });
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

  
  const publicPaths = [
    "/login",
    "/register",
    "/api/auth",
    "/_next/static",
    "/_next/image",
  ];

  
  const isPublicPath = publicPaths.some((path) => pathname.startsWith(path));

  if (!isPublicPath && !session) {
    const loginUrl = new URL("/login", req.url);
    loginUrl.searchParams.set("callbackUrl", req.url); 
    return NextResponse.redirect(loginUrl);
  }

 
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
  matcher: ["/", "/terms", "/contact", "/dashboard", "/profile"], 
};
```

**app/login/page.tsx:**

```
import LoginForm from "@/app/ui/login-form";

export default function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <main className="flex items-center justify-center md:h-screen">
      <div className="relative mx-auto flex w-full max-w-[400px] flex-col space-y-2.5 p-4 md:-mt-32">
        <div className="flex h-20 w-full items-end rounded-lg bg-blue-500 p-3 md:h-36">
          <div className="w-32 text-white md:w-36">Login</div>
        </div>
        <LoginForm />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

**login-form.tsx:**

```
"use client";

import {
  UserIcon,
  KeyIcon,
  ExclamationCircleIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import { ArrowRightIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { Button } from "./button";
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";
import { authenticate } from "@/app/lib/actions";

export default function LoginForm() {
  const [errorMessage, dispatch] = useFormState(authenticate, undefined);

  return (
    <form action={dispatch} className="space-y-3">
      <div className="flex-1 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 px-6 pb-4 pt-8">
        <h1 className="mb-3 text-2xl">Please log in to continue.</h1>
        <div className="w-full">
          <div>
            <label
              className="mb-3 mt-5 block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
              htmlFor="username" 
            >
              Username
            </label>
            <div className="relative">
              <input
                className="peer block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-[9px] pl-10 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
                id="username" 
                type="text" 
                name="username" 
                placeholder="Enter your username" 
                required
              />
              <UserIcon className="pointer-events-none absolute left-3 top-1/2 h-[18px] w-[18px] -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900" />{" "}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-4">
            <label
              className="mb-3 mt-5 block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
              htmlFor="password"
            >
              Password
            </label>
            <div className="relative">
              <input
                className="peer block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-[9px] pl-10 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
                id="password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Enter password"
                required
                minLength={6}
              />
              <KeyIcon className="pointer-events-none absolute left-3 top-1/2 h-[18px] w-[18px] -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <LoginButton />
        <div
          className="flex h-8 items-end space-x-1"
          aria-live="polite"
          aria-atomic="true"
        >
          {errorMessage && (
            <>
              <ExclamationCircleIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-red-500" />
              <p className="text-sm text-red-500">{errorMessage}</p>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

function LoginButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return (
    <Button className="mt-4 w-full" aria-disabled={pending}>
      Log in <ArrowRightIcon className="ml-auto h-5 w-5 text-gray-50" />
    </Button>
  );
}
```

**app/lib/actions.ts:**

```
"use server";

import { signIn } from "@/auth";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";

export async function authenticate(
  prevState: string | undefined,
  formData: FormData
) {
  try {
    await signIn("credentials", formData);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      console.error("Authentication error:", error);
      switch (error.type) {
        case "CredentialsSignin":
          return "Invalid credentials.";
        default:
          console.log(error.message);
          return "Something got wrong." + error.message;
      }
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is challenging indeed. It took me a few days to implement it successfully. I'll try to help you. Please tweak the code examples according to your needs. This is a real working example.

1. Install the packages below (I recommend to use those specific versions. I had some troubles using the latest beta version of the next-auth with the next v.14.0.3)

[image: The packages]

2. Add auth.ts file
   Put it at the root level of the project

DESCRIPTION: In this file, we manage a few things such as log in process, redirecting unauthorized users to the login page, save refresh token, refresh the expired access token, etc.. Please observe it carefully.

```
import { cookies, headers } from "next/headers"

import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

import { privateRoutes } from "@/contains/contants" // an array like ["/", "/account"]

// @ts-ignore
async function refreshAccessToken(token) { // this is our refresh token method
    console.log("Now refreshing the expired token...")
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/auth/refresh`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers(),
            body: JSON.stringify({ userID: token.userId })
        })

        const { success, data } = await res.json()

        if (!success) {
            console.log("The token could not be refreshed!")
            throw data
        }

        console.log("The token has been refreshed successfully.")

        // get some data from the new access token such as exp (expiration time)
        const decodedAccessToken = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(data.accessToken.split(".")[1], "base64").toString())

        return {
            ...token,
            accessToken: data.accessToken,
            refreshToken: data.refreshToken ?? token.refreshToken,
            idToken: data.idToken,
            accessTokenExpires: decodedAccessToken["exp"] * 1000,
            error: "",
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

        // return an error if somethings goes wrong
        return {
            ...token,
            error: "RefreshAccessTokenError", // attention!
        }
    }
}

export const config = {
    trustHost: true,
    theme: {
        logo: "https://next-auth.js.org/img/logo/logo-sm.png",
    },
    providers: [
        // we use credentials provider here
        CredentialsProvider({
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: "email",
                    type: "email",
                    placeholder: "jsmith@example.com",
                },
                password: {
                    label: "password",
                    type: "password",
                },
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const payload = {
                    email: credentials.email,
                    password: credentials.password,
                }

                // external api for users to log in, change it with your own endpoint
                const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/auth/login`, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
                })

                const user = await res.json()

                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error(user.message)
                }

                if (res.ok && user) {
                    const prefix = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "__Dev-" : ""

                    // we set http only cookie here to store refresh token information as we will not append it to our session to avoid maximum size warning for the session cookie (4096 bytes)
                    cookies().set({
                        name: `${prefix}xxx.refresh-token`,
                        value: user.refreshToken,
                        httpOnly: true,
                        sameSite: "strict",
                        secure: true,
                    } as any)

                    return user
                }

                return null
            }
        })
    ],
    // this is required
    secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
    // our custom login page
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
            if (account && user) {
                token.id = user.id
                token.accessToken = user.accessToken
                token.refreshToken = user.refreshToken
                token.role = "Unknown" // the user role

                const decodedAccessToken = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(user.accessToken.split(".")[1], "base64").toString())

                if (decodedAccessToken) {
                    token.userId = decodedAccessToken["sub"] as string
                    token.accessTokenExpires = decodedAccessToken["exp"] * 1000
                }

                // get some info about user from the id token
                const decodedIdToken = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(user.idToken.split(".")[1], "base64").toString())

                if (decodedIdToken) {
                    token.email = decodedIdToken["email"]
                    token.cognitoGroups = decodedIdToken["cognito:groups"]
                    token.role = decodedIdToken["cognito:groups"].length ? decodedIdToken["cognito:groups"][0] : "Unknown"
                }
            }

            // if our access token has not expired yet, return all information except the refresh token
            if (token.accessTokenExpires && (Date.now() < Number(token.accessTokenExpires))) {
                const { refreshToken, ...rest } = token

                return rest
            }

            // if our access token has expired, refresh it and return the result
            return await refreshAccessToken(token)
        },

        async session({ session, token }) {
            console.log("session => ", session)

            return {
                ...session,
                user: {
                    ...session.user,
                    id: token.id as string,
                    email: token.email as string,
                    cognitoGroups: token.cognitoGroups as string[],
                    accessToken: token.accessToken as string,
                    accessTokenExpires: token.accessTokenExpires as number,
                    role: token.role as string
                },
                error: token.error,
            }
        },
        authorized({ request, auth }) {
            const { pathname } = request.nextUrl

            // get the route name from the url such as "/about"
            const searchTerm = request.nextUrl.pathname.split("/").slice(0, 2).join("/")

            // if the private routes array includes the search term, we ask authorization here and forward any unauthorized users to the login page
            if (privateRoutes.includes(searchTerm)) {
                console.log(`${!!auth ? "Can" : "Cannot"} access private route ${searchTerm}`)
                return !!auth
            // if the pathname starts with one of the routes below and the user is already logged in, forward the user to the home page
            } else if (pathname.startsWith("/login") || pathname.startsWith("/forgot-password") || pathname.startsWith("/signup")) {
                const isLoggedIn = !!auth

                if (isLoggedIn) {
                    return Response.redirect(new URL("/", request.nextUrl))
                }

                return true
            }

            return true
        },
    },
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
} satisfies NextAuthConfig

export const { auth, handlers } = NextAuth(config)
```

Our route handler to refresh the access token which we call in the file above (path: app/api/auth/refresh)

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json()

    const prefix = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "__Dev-" : ""

    const payload = {
        refreshToken: cookies().get(`${prefix}xxx.refresh-token` as any)?.value,
        userID: body.userID,
    }

    // change it with your own endpoint
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/auth/refresh`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })

    const data = await res.json()

    return Response.json({
        success: res.ok,
        status: res.status,
        data,
    })
}
```

3. Add custom types

To be able to use our own session props, we need to add type folder at the root level of the project and put next-auth.d.ts file inside it

This is our next-auth.d.ts file, typescript is going to complain without it

```
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface User {
        id: string
        email: string
        cognitoGroups: string[]
        accessToken: string
        refreshToken: string
        idToken: string
        exp: number
        role: string
    }

    interface Session {
        user: User & DefaultSession["user"]
        expires: string
        error: string
    }
}
```

4. Add middleware.ts file
   This file should be nested at the same level with your app folder

```
export { auth as middleware } from "auth"

export const config = {
    matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
}
```

5. Add [...nextauth] folder

Now, we add [...nextauth] folder under app/api/auth path and add route.ts file inside it with the content below

```
import { handlers } from "auth"
export const { GET, POST } = handlers
```

Don't forget to add auth path inside tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "auth": ["./auth"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["process.d.ts", "next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

6. Add your env variables
   In your .env.local file which is at the root level again (let's assume you run this app on http://localhost:3000), you should add those vars

```
API_BASE_URL=https://api.yourdomain.com // external api for login, remember?
AUTH_SECRET=ac7uc0598805655a2b015a789ba889e0 // generate your secret here
AUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/auth // important, you will have problems such as wrong redirect url issue without it
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

You wonder the production?

```
API_BASE_URL=https://api.yourdomain.com // external api for login, remember?
AUTH_SECRET=bx7fg0593375655a2b015a789cc089x9 // just another secret
AUTH_URL=https://www.yourdomain.com/api/auth
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=https://www.yourdomain.com
```

Don't forget to add those vars in your Dockerfile as well (if you use any)

7. Sign in

Like in many examples, you can convert some part of your page into a client component like below and call it from your server component page. I added that client component part as an example.

```
"use client"

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import type { SignInResponse } from "next-auth/lib/client"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"

import { Route } from "@/routers/types"

export default function LoginForm() {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()

    async function login({ email, password }: any) { // whatever your type
        const callbackUrl = searchParams.get("callbackUrl")
        signIn("credentials", {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            redirect: false,
        })
            .then((res: SignInResponse | undefined) => {
                if (!res) {
                    alert("No response!")
                    return
                }

                if (!res.ok)
                    alert("Something went wrong!")
                else if (res.error) {
                    console.log(res.error)

                    if (res.error == "CallbackRouteError")
                        alert("Could not login! Please check your credentials.")
                    else
                        alert(`Internal Server Error: ${res.error}`)
                } else {
                    if (callbackUrl)
                        router.push(callbackUrl as Route)
                    else
                        router.push("/")
                }
            })
    }

    return (
        <>
            // ...
        <>
    )
}
```

If the access token cannot be refreshed somehow, force the users to log out. I've put this logic inside the header.

```
"use client"

import { Fragment, useCallback, useEffect } from "react"
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react"

export default function AComponentInsideHeader({ className = "" }: Props) {
    const { data: session } = useSession()
    // you can directly call this method from your log out button somewhere in this component
    const logout = useCallback(() => {
        const accessToken = session?.user?.accessToken || undefined

        fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/auth/logout`, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({ accessToken })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                /* send log to the Sentry if the endpoint fails
                if (!data.success)
                    notifySentry("Could not log out!")
                 */
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                /* send log to the Sentry if an error occurs
                notifySentry(error)
                 */
            })
            .finally(async () => {
                await signOut({ callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/login` })
            })
    }, [session])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('session: ', session)
        if (session?.error === "RefreshAccessTokenError") { // remember that error?
            // force the user to log out if the session has RefreshAccessTokenError
            logout()
        }
    }, [session, logout])

    return (
        <>
            //..
        </>
    )
}
```

Our route handler for logout (path: app/api/auth/logout)

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json()

    // change with your own endpoint
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/auth/logout`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${body.accessToken}`,
        },
    })

    const prefix = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "__Dev-" : ""
    // remove cookies after
    cookies().getAll().map(cookie => {
        if (cookie.name.startsWith(`${prefix}xxx.`))
            cookies().delete(cookie.name as any)
    })

    return Response.json({
        success: res.ok,
        status: res.status,
    })
}
```

THAT'S IT.

Tell me if you have any issues.

**BONUS**

I give you a HOC here to implement role based access

```
/****** withAuth HOC ******
Use this HOC if your page needs authentication to be accessed
- If the page to be accessed requires only authentication (a logged in user),
pass an empty array as allowedRoles
- If the page to be accessed requires both authentication and authorization (a logged in user with a specific role),
pass a string array as allowedRoles
 ******/
import React from "react"

import { redirect } from "next/navigation"

import { auth } from "auth"

import PageFourOhThree from "@/app/(unauthorized)/four-oh-three/page" // you design it

/* eslint-disable react/display-name */
export default function withAuth(allowedRoles: string[]) {
    return function <P extends object>(Component: React.FC<P>) {
        return async function (props: P) {
            const sess = await auth()

            // redirect the user to the login page if not logged in
            if (!sess)
                redirect("/login")

            // show 403 page if the user has not one of the required roles to access the page
            if (allowedRoles.length)
                if (!allowedRoles.includes(sess.user?.role)) {
                    return (
                        <PageFourOhThree />
                    )
                }

            return <Component {...(props as P)} />
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you can use it

```
import withAuth from "@/hoc/withAuth"
//..

export interface PageAboutProps {}

const PageAbout: FC<PageAboutProps> = () => {
    //..
}

export default withAuth(["Admin", "SuperAdmin"])(PageAbout) // which means only the users with Admin or SuperAdmin role can access to this page
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comprehensive example how to use auth js 5. One thing that is still puzzling me is that I'm getting an error saying useSession must be wrapped in <SessionProvider/>. What is the correct way in auth.js to use the useSession? Should I wrap the rootlayout inside the SessionProvider element?

Comment: No, you just need to wrap the component in which you need session information . Think it like this way: you use session in ComponentA which is a sub component of ComponentB. You wrap ComponentA with SessionProvider in ComponentB.

Comment: Thanks, got it working using the above explanation.